# std::forward compiling error VS2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, templates, compiler-errors, std

I am getting a weird error that I can't understand(since it's from a native file of VS) from file *`utility`*(it's located in **`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\`**), it is being compiled in my project with Visual C++ 10.0.

> 'std::forward' : cannot convert parameter 1 from '' to '&'

```
template<class _Other1, class _Other2>
pair(_Other1&& _Val1, _Other2&& _Val2)
: _Mybase(_STD forward<_Other1>(_Val1), _STD forward<_Other2>(_Val2))
{   // construct from moved values
}
```

Can anyone explain this error? It seems to me very strange, but I'm totally new to C++ and I don't understand how to fix it.

---

The error seems to be here:

```
std::map<std::string, DWORD>::value_type("SOME_STRING", 8192);
```

And the compilation reports this:

```
see reference to function template instantiation 
'std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2>::pair<const char(&)[12],>(_Other1,_Other2 &&)' 
being compiled with
  [
      _Ty1=const std::string,
      _Ty2=DWORD,
      _Other1=const char (&)[12],
      _Other2=
  ]
```

Comment: Please post slightly more complete code.

Comment: We need to see *your* code, not that of the standard library.

Comment: An [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) would be ideal.

Comment: The error is in your code, not the library one. So post the code that calls `std::forward`, that causes the error.

Comment: @Angew, the extremely weird thing is that I'm not using `std::forward` in my project(the compiling error points directly to that line of code in utility).

Comment: @LightStyle Sure. But you're using *something* which uses `std::forward` internally (based on the error, a `pair` or a `map`), and either (1) you've hit a standard library bug (very unlikely), or (2) you're using that *something* wrong (extremely likely).

Comment: @LightStyle Also note that template errors usually look like "error XYZ when instantiating ABC when instantiating DEF when instantiating GHI when instantiated here: `your_file_and_line.cpp`" To find the cause of the error, you must look at `your_file_and_line.cpp`, not at `ABC`.

Comment: @Angew, I posted the code and the relative compilation error. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction, I didn't know how template errors worked ;)

Comment: Well, that line compiles with Clang (with `DWORD` replaced with `unsigned`), but the line itself doesn't actually do anything. It creates a pair, but doesn't do anything with it.

Comment: I know it does nothing at all, but it's just a portion of code which uses map, but it is pushed in a vector of maps, so it's actually used.  I think the error is in the instantiation(hope I spelled it right lol), so I passed the line which looked interesting to me

Comment: Unfortunately, I have no way of testing on VS2010, but try replacing it with `std::make_pair(std::string("SOME_STRING"), 8192)`

Answer (score 0):

It seems the compiler is incapable of coping with the string literal passed in. I don't know whether it's a bug in the standard library implementation VS2010 uses, or whether it hits an edge case in the standard (and is actually supposed to fail), but either way, you can solve it by explicitly creating a `std::string` from the literal:

```
std::map<std::string, DWORD>::value_type(std::string("SOME_STRING"), 8192);
```